# Authlogic: Setting expiration date for cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, authlogic

Is there a way to set the expiration date for the session cookies created by Authlogic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation for the [Cookies session plugin](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/Session/Cookies/Config%3aremember_me_for). In your UserSession you should be able to specify:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  remember_me_for 1.day
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to specify remember_me(true) or it won't work.
So for example:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  remember_me(true)
  remember_me_for(300)
  ...
```

Comment: **Thank you** for the `remember_me(true)` bit. I was losing it.